# Select points on image to retrieve coordinates

Tags: android, image, coordinates

I'm trying to (manually) select a section from an image and need to know the coordinates (4 points of the square) of the selected section.

This is an Android app, I know there is a crop intent but don't want to actually crop the section, just retrieve the coordinates of the four points of the squared section.

Any ideas?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the XY coordinates using Java Function
like below

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);


        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

                    //  textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x" + String.valueOf(event.getY()));
                    Log.e("X",String.valueOf(event.getX())+"");
                    Log.e("y",String.valueOf(event.getY())+"");
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't even think about that. I'll give it a go. :) Cheers!